# How to install GNS3 on Debian12

Tags: debian, gns3

I tried following the docs on their website under the Debian distro section but I get the following output.
https://docs.gns3.com/docs/getting-started/installation/linux

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y python3-pip python3-pyqt5 python3-pyqt5.qtsvg \
python3-pyqt5.qtwebsockets \
qemu qemu-kvm qemu-utils libvirt-clients libvirt-daemon-system virtinst \
wireshark xtightvncviewer apt-transport-https \
ca-certificates curl gnupg2 software-properties-common
```

```
Hit:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease                                      
Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease                              
Get:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gns3/ppa/ubuntu trusty InRelease [15.4 kB]      
Hit:5 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                  
Err:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gns3/ppa/ubuntu trusty InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 9A2FD067A2E3EF7B
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/gns3/ppa/ubuntu trusty InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 9A2FD067A2E3EF7B
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/gns3/ppa/ubuntu trusty InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'qemu-system-x86' instead of 'qemu-kvm'
Package qemu is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'qemu' has no installation candidate
```

I am new to Linux too so not sure where I am going wrong here.

Thanks!

Comment: If you have Debian 12 why exactly did you follow instructions for for the long gone and unsupported Debian 8.x (Jessie)? You should've tried the instructions for "Buster" (and hoped for the best). In any case instructions that tell you to add Ubuntu repos to Debian should always be taken with a grain of salt.

Comment: So, start by removing the PPA you added.

Comment: Removed PPA stuff from /etc/apt/sources.list 
Ran the commands listed under buster but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can install GNS3 from Python3 PyPI and run it in a [Python virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html).

Firstly, install the required Debian packages.

```
sudo apt install python3-pip python3-venv python3-pyqt5.qtsvg python3-pyqt5.qtwebsockets
```

Then create a Python virtual environment

```
python3 -m venv gns3env
```

Activate the virtual environment

```
source gns3env/bin/activate
```

Install the required packages from PyPI

```
pip install pyqt5
pip install gns3-server
pip install gns3-gui
```

You should now be able to launch the gns3 gui from a shell prompt.

```
(gns3env) $ gns3
```