# Cannot open GNS3 without being signed in as root in my /home/ directory

Tags: gns3

I am currently running Debian 12.5

I used the instructions found here to install GNS3
[How to install GNS3 on Debian12](https://superuser.com/questions/1788720/how-to-install-gns3-on-debian12)

Although it was an initial success. I am finding that in order to run GNS3, I have to open a terminal and login with my root account. Navigate to my home directory as root to create a virtual environment and then activate that environment before opening GNS3. So it looks like this:

root@computername:/home/nonrootaccount/

Then create a Python virtual environment using:

python3 -m venv gns3env

Then activate the virtual environment using:

source gns3env/bin/activate

before I get a (gns3env) $ prompt in which I can type in GNS3 and then the program will open.

I have added myself to the sudoers group to make sure that wasn't an issue. I'm unsure how to setup GNS3 so that I don't have to do this each time to open it as root, which isn't the best of ideas anyway.

Thank you for your time.